# How to send data from one mobile to multiple mobiles in android

Tags: android

I'm Making an android prototype application similar to uber. So I started with building two applications `user` & `Driver`,and my question is .

> 1. Is it possible to make user app send a request or whatever to driver app even if these two apps are located in different devices.
> 2. If that possible I want to make user send his request to the nearby driver & if the driver ignores that request. The request goes
>      to another driver and so on .
> 3. I'm using `parse` as a backend server .

Comment: You can use GCM push notification to send request.

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can push notification to all and ... who confirm it as first then disable request...

Comment: Can you give me more detailed answer please ?!